# Multiple output files in a single rake profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, cucumber, rake

I've created a rake file to run my Cucumber features through. In said Rake file, I have several profiles set up:

```
headless: BROWSER_TYPE=headless -f html -o "HBreport.html"
firefox: BROWSER_TYPE=firefox -f html -o "ffreport.html"
ie: BROWSER_TYPE=ie
Headless_JSON: BROWSER_TYPE=headless -f pretty -f json -o "report.json"
```

Would anyone be able to tell me if it is possible to run each rake profile and have it output two different reports?

For example, the "headless" profile above currently outputs a report into a html file for easier reading for stakeholders, but it would be useful to have that profile output both a .html and .json file for the developers. Is this possible, or will I have to run both a .html and a .json profile to get both outputs?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just add further arguments to each profile. Seems so obvious now...

headless: BROWSER_TYPE=headless -f pretty -f html -o "hbreport.html"
firefox: BROWSER_TYPE=firefox -f pretty -f html -o "ffreport.html"
ie: BROWSER_TYPE=ie -f pretty -f html -o "iereport.html"